# Unit Testing login token

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am working on adding unit testing to my application framework and everything is going well. I however have run into an issue testing if the token has expired or is still active.

I was able to test if the user token was created by mocking the response for my /login call with a token I saved for a test user, however this only works until the token expires. I have no way to manually expire the token or reset the expiration time to the future.

My auth factory:

```
auth.isLoggedIn = function(){
    var token = SS.getObj('appToken');
    if(token){
        var payload = JSON.parse($window.atob(token.split('.')[1]));
        return payload.exp > Date.now() / 1000;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

And my unit tests:

```
describe('auth.isLoggedIn()', function () {
    it('should return false if a user is not logged in', function () {
      expect(auth.isLoggedIn()).toEqual(false); // This test passes 100%
    });

    it('should return true if a user is logged in', function () {
      user = {
        email: 'bwayne@wayneenterprise.com',
        password: 'password123'
      };
      $httpBackend.expectPOST('/login').respond({ token: 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6NywiZW1haWwiOiJid2F5bmVAd2F5bmVlbnRlcnByaXNlLmNvbSIsIm5hbWUiOiJCcnVjZSBXYXluZSIsImV4cCI6MTQzODI4NDYwNywiaWF0IjoxNDM4MjgxMDA3fQ.2rpGJ1c5dVi1EiPo0C5JIdva7MonutCYmotP5-pB_N4' }); // I copied a valid token from a test user, but I can't change it since I'm just copying an old token.
      auth.login(user);
      $httpBackend.flush();
      expect(auth.isLoggedIn()).toEqual(true); // This test passes if the above token has a valid time/date, however I can't set the time/date so it usually fails
    });

    it('should return false if a users token has expired', function () {
      user = {
        email: 'bwayne@wayneenterprise.com',
        password: 'password123'
      };
      $httpBackend.expectPOST('/login').respond({ token: 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6NywiZW1haWwiOiJid2F5bmVAd2F5bmVlbnRlcnByaXNlLmNvbSIsIm5hbWUiOiJCcnVjZSBXYXluZSIsImV4cCI6MTQzODI4NDYwNywiaWF0IjoxNDM4MjgxMDA3fQ.2rpGJ1c5dVi1EiPo0C5JIdva7MonutCYmotP5-pB_N4' });
      auth.login(user);
      $httpBackend.flush();
      expect(auth.isLoggedIn()).toEqual(false); // This test fails if the date/time has expired, again I can't set that so it's usually passing, as the token has expired.
    });
  });
```

I suspect the proper way to do this is to actually create a valid token during the test, but I'm not sure how to do that as it's handled by the node server who's responses I mock to avoid relying on a server response in my tests.

Comment: Does your app controls the expiration of the token? Shouldnt it be the server's responsibility?

Comment: The server creates the token and set's an expiration for 30 minutes in the future then returns the token to the application. If the token is not updated within 30 minutes it has expired and is no longer valid. My application simply checks if the token has expired before sending the request to the server, if it has expired the app routes the user to the login as the request their trying to make will be rejected by the server. Once they log in and have a valid token, their original request will be completed. This prevents bombarding my server with requests from invalid users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have no way to manually expire the token or reset the expiration time to the future.

Luckily, you have nice way to do it and make this statement: `return payload.exp > Date.now() / 1000;` more predictable. Jasmine has pretty nice feature to mock `Date` object and you can use it in the following way:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    jasmine.clock().install();
    jasmine.clock().mockDate(new Date(2015, 8, 28)); //You can set any date
});

afterEach(function() {
    jasmine.clock().uninstall(); //Don't forget to uninstall your mock
});
```

With this approach you can refactor your tests to something like this:

```
it('should return true if a user is logged in', function () {
  jasmine.clock().install();
  jasmine.clock().mockDate(new Date(2015, 8, 28)); //Here you should set some VALID date for token, which you're defining below

  user = {
    email: 'bwayne@wayneenterprise.com',
    password: 'password123'
  };
  $httpBackend.expectPOST('/login').respond({ token: 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6NywiZW1haWwiOiJid2F5bmVAd2F5bmVlbnRlcnByaXNlLmNvbSIsIm5hbWUiOiJCcnVjZSBXYXluZSIsImV4cCI6MTQzODI4NDYwNywiaWF0IjoxNDM4MjgxMDA3fQ.2rpGJ1c5dVi1EiPo0C5JIdva7MonutCYmotP5-pB_N4' }); // I copied a valid token from a test user, but I can't change it since I'm just copying an old token.
  auth.login(user);
  $httpBackend.flush();
  expect(auth.isLoggedIn()).toEqual(true); // This test passes if the above token has a valid time/date, however I can't set the time/date so it usually fails

  jasmine.clock().uninstall(); //Clean up
});

it('should return false if a users token has expired', function () {
  jasmine.clock().install();
  jasmine.clock().mockDate(new Date(2020, 11, 30)); //Here you should set some INVALID date for token, which you're defining below
  user = {
    email: 'bwayne@wayneenterprise.com',
    password: 'password123'
  };
  $httpBackend.expectPOST('/login').respond({ token: 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6NywiZW1haWwiOiJid2F5bmVAd2F5bmVlbnRlcnByaXNlLmNvbSIsIm5hbWUiOiJCcnVjZSBXYXluZSIsImV4cCI6MTQzODI4NDYwNywiaWF0IjoxNDM4MjgxMDA3fQ.2rpGJ1c5dVi1EiPo0C5JIdva7MonutCYmotP5-pB_N4' });
  auth.login(user);
  $httpBackend.flush();
  expect(auth.isLoggedIn()).toEqual(false); // This test fails if the date/time has expired, again I can't set that so it's usually passing, as the token has expired.

  jasmine.clock().uninstall(); //Clean up
});
```

Now, as you can see, we can manually set past or future date for `Date.now()` function, when it's needed.

[See Jasmine Clock section with an example.](http://jasmine.github.io/2.2/introduction.html)

---

You can also mock `Date.now` in traditional way with `spyOn`:

```
spyOn(Date, 'now').and.returnValue(2000);
```

It'll look a little bit cleaner:

```
it('should return false if a users token has expired', function () {
  spyOn(Date, 'now').and.returnValue(2000); //Here you should set some INVALID count of milliseconds for token, which you're defining below
  user = {
    email: 'bwayne@wayneenterprise.com',
    password: 'password123'
  };
  $httpBackend.expectPOST('/login').respond({ token: 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6NywiZW1haWwiOiJid2F5bmVAd2F5bmVlbnRlcnByaXNlLmNvbSIsIm5hbWUiOiJCcnVjZSBXYXluZSIsImV4cCI6MTQzODI4NDYwNywiaWF0IjoxNDM4MjgxMDA3fQ.2rpGJ1c5dVi1EiPo0C5JIdva7MonutCYmotP5-pB_N4' });
  auth.login(user);
  $httpBackend.flush();
  expect(auth.isLoggedIn()).toEqual(false); // This test fails if the date/time has expired, again I can't set that so it's usually passing, as the token has expired.
});
```

Comment: This mocks a new date in my unit test, however Date.now() is called in my auth factory, after some testing I found that Date.now() inside the auth factory still returns the current date/time not the mocked date/time returned by the unit test so the test still fails.

Comment: @efarley, that's strange, because in my tests Date.now() returns mocked date. What version of Jasmine do you use? You can try mocking particularly `now` function from `Date`. See my updated answer.

Comment: It sounds like you miss read my comment, the mocked date works in my test, the issue is that Date.now() is located in my angular services file not my tests. Setting the date in the test does no good when the service is checking against the real date. I need a way to push the mocked date from my test and into my service where it's used. Date.now() is not called anywhere in the test it's self.

Comment: I found the problem, I was calling jasmine.clock().uninstall() before the service function was called, which removed my mocked time.